# Combining values as dictionaries in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have data that looks like this:

```
main_data = sc.parallelize([
    ('key001', 'value001'),
    ('key001', 'value002'),
    ('key001', 'value001'),
    ('key002', 'value003'),
    ('key002', 'value003'),
    ('key002', 'value001'),
    ('key002', 'value004'),
    ('key003', 'value005'),
    ('key003', 'value006'),
])
```

And what I would like to have is a structure where every key contains a dictionary with the counts of every value, like:

```
('key001': {'value001': 2, 'value002': 1},
 'key002': {'value003': 2, 'value001': 1, 'value004': 1},
 'key003': {'value005': 1, 'value006': 1})
```

My initial idea was to first map the values of `main_data` to a `1` value so I could then sum the result, like:

`main_data.mapValues(lambda t: {t: 1})`

And after that I understand I should probably use `aggregateByKey`, but it's really escaping me how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
from collections import Counter
list_that_you_seek = main_data.map(lambda x:(x[0],[x[1]])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y).map(lambda x:(x[0],Counter(x[1])).collect()
```

Comment: It's enough to do `mapValues` at the end: `main_data.map(lambda x:(x[0],[x[1]])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).mapValues(lambda x: Counter(x)).collect()`

Comment: My idea was to try and get a structure where I'd have the key and an array with all the values for that key, but I really did not think of using an array and the sum operation to "append" to the array, which actually makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way is to sort RDD first using key and value then use `groupBy` and `Counter` afterward.

```
from collections import Counter

group_key = main_data.map(lambda x: (*x, 1)).sortBy(lambda x: (x[0], x[1])).groupBy(lambda x: x[0])
count_value = group_key.map(lambda x: (x[0], Counter(x[1])))
```

Consider using PySpark Dataframe will also reduce some amount of code

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func

df = main_data.toDF(['key', 'value'])
gr = df.groupby(['key', 'value'])
count = gr.count()
count.rdd.collect()

# [Row(key='key002', value='value003', count=2),
#  Row(key='key003', value='value005', count=1),
#  ...
```